# Can you only have 12 games on the switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

On the Switch Home screen, there are only 12 boxes in the game menu. Does this mean that only 12 games can be installed on a Switch?

Comment: If you downvote please tell me why.

Comment: Downvoted because all you had to do was install a 13th game, and if you had but didnt see anything, your question wasnt what was asked.

Comment: I dont have 12 games and I dont have enough money or storage space to buy 12 games.

Comment: So, you have no means to know through experience, and rather than search the Nintendo forum, asked here?

Comment: Down-vote reasons:  1) It's not actually affecting you 2) There's no way, if the console **IS** limited to 12 games, that people will not flip out and go crazy.  Using plain logic tells you this is not a problem.

Comment: The fact that the answer to a question is theoretically discoverable is not a valid reason to downvote a question. (On the contrary, it's a fantastic reason to _upvote_ a question.) "It doesn't affect you" is also not a valid reason to downvote a question.

Comment: Stack Exchange is for questions and answers; it is exactly the place to ask a question like this.

Comment: I agree with rensa. We put questions on Arqade so that other people can learn from the answer. Just because it doesn't apply to the person that asked it isn't a valid reason to vote it down.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can have more than 12 games installed on your Switch, but only the 12 with the most recent activity will show up on your Home Screen.

As soon as you hit your 13th game, a new icon will show up called "**All Software**".

[image: Screenshot of "All Software" button]

This will let you browse through all of your games in a grid, rather than a line.

[image: Screenshot of "All Software" grid]